# Filling numpy array upon iteration

Tags: python, numpy

I never understood why this is not working

```
import numpy as np
cube = np.empty((10, 100, 100), dtype=np.float32)

for plane in cube:
    plane = np.random.random(10000).reshape(100, 100)
```

With this the `cube` is still empty (just zeros). I have to do it like that to make it work:

```
for idx in range(10):
    cube[idx] = np.random.random(10000).reshape(100, 100)
```

Why is that?
thanks

Comment: because you're operating on the iterable rather than a slice/view on the array

Comment: So, is there a way to directly edit the cube with the iterable, or do I have to stick with the index?

Comment: @HansSnah: you need to use `for plane in cube: plane[:] = np.random.random(10000).reshape(100, 100)` in that case.

Comment: @ajcr Now that is genius!! Thanks for that. I do understand now why my first example doesn't change anything, but what difference dies the [:] make?

Comment: No problem. `[:]` gets a view into the plane array and triggers `__setitem__`, so the cube array gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because each iteration of the loop you first assign an element of `cube` to `plane` then in the loop suite you assign a different thing to `plane` and you never change anything in `cube`.

Python is cool because you can play around in the shell and figure out how things work:

```
>>> a = [0,0,0,0]
>>> for thing in a:
    print(thing),
    thing = 2
    print(thing),
    print(a)


0 2 [0, 0, 0, 0]
0 2 [0, 0, 0, 0]
0 2 [0, 0, 0, 0]
0 2 [0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

[Iterating Over Arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html)